# Кеш LoadingCache от apache commons не использует синхронизацию в методе getAll

Tags: java, кэширование

Я создаю вот такой вот кеш LoadingCache:

```java
LoadingCache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String load(String o) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("load: " + o);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return "value-" + o;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> loadAll(Iterable<? extends String> keys) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("loadAll: " + keys);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (String key : keys) {
            result.put(key, "value-" + key);
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

В этом кеше я реализовал методы `load` и `loadAll`. В обеих случаях я имитирую задержку сети в 2 секунды с помощью `Thread.sleep(2000);`.

Теперь попробуем из разных потоков одновременно обратиться к кешу вот таким кодом:

```java
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    service.submit(() -> {
        try {
            cache.get("key1");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    service.submit(() -> {
        try {
            cache.getAll(Arrays.asList("key1", "key2"));
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Этот код достает из кеша значения по ключам `key1` и `key2`. Два раза вызывается `load` и два раза вызывается `loadAll`. Результат работы теста:

```
load: key1
loadAll: [key1, key2]
loadAll: [key1, key2]
```

Метод `load` работает корректно, загрузка ключа `key1` была вызвана только один раз, второй вызов совершил синхронизацию и потом получил значение из кеша.

А вот методы `loadAll` вообще не синхронизируются. Во-первых, они вызывают загрузку `key1`, когда этот ключ первее загружает метод `load`. Во-вторых, метод `loadAll` даже относительно друг друга не делают синхронизации и вызывают загрузку одних и тех же значений.

Если бы все работало идеально, тогда вывод должен был быть таким:

```
load: key1
loadAll: [key2]
```

Метод `load` один раз загрузил бы `key1`, а `loadAll` один раз загрузил `key2`. Все остальные обращения к кешу должны были синхронизироваться и просто получить значение из кеша.

Как решить эту проблему? Есть ли кеш, где реализована корректно эта логика?

Answer (score 0):

Спустя время я могу ответить на свои вопросы из прошлого.

> Есть ли кеш, где реализована корректно эта логика?

В данный момент нет. Почему это не сделано в LoadingCache объяснено тут:
https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1711#issuecomment-69740046

Но это не значит, что подобную логику реализовать нельзя. Однажды я создам свой кеш с корректно работающей функцией getAll. Когда сделаю, добавлю тут ссылку на него.